# Why can't I cast my nested NSUserDefaults dictionary?

Tags: swift

I am trying to set and get a nested dictionary, but I cannot get the casting correct. The debugger says that:

```
l = AnyObject?  Some 
c = nil 
d = nil
```

And here is the code

```
        var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        userDefaults.removeObjectForKey("orch_array")
        userDefaults.setObject([orchId:[]],forKey: "orch_array")

        let b = NSUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("orch_array")
        let l = b?[orchId]
        let c = b?[orchId] as? [String:String]
        let d = b?[orchId] as? [String:[String]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s because you’re not creating a dictionary inside the dictionary with `setObject` – you’re creating an array (`[]` not `[:]`).

This appears to work correctly:

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.removeObjectForKey("orch_array")
userDefaults.setObject([orchId:[:]],forKey: "orch_array")

let b = NSUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("orch_array")
let c = b?[orchId] as? [String:String]
let d = b?[orchId] as? [String:[String]]
```